# When is a delegate called?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, delegates, delegation

When I set up a collectionView for example and I set a VC as its delegate (UICollectionViewDelegate), I can't understand when the delegate is called.

Is it called before the collectionView is displayed. or when it is already displayed?
Because some methods seem to provide important feature for laying out of the object (such as number of items in section) but other methods seem to provide less "important task".

Till now I couldn't grasp this important concept of delegation in iOS development.

Comment: Do you mean UICollectionViewDelegate's methods?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm correcting it rn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delegation methods are called according to events.
please refer to this link
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate

For example, scrollViewDidScroll method is called when user is scrolling.
And collectionView methods is called when the collectionview is mounted.

The delegate can be meant as interface and it is calling defined methods in UICollectionView class.

Comment: Thank you so much, and so my question here is: how do I know when actually the collectionView or other object calls its delegate upon a touch or something happening from the user? What I mean is: I would like to know exactly when the object calls its delegate. Is it possible to see the code or not?

Comment: the code is not open source, so no you cannot see it. the delegates are called in response to events. setting the data source calls the data related methods, reloading calls some of these too, then there are UI related ones. your best bet is to print out something like "numberOfItems called" in each of the methods and then do things to see what happens and when, or read the documentation for each delegate method

Answer (score 1):

As Bojan said UICollectionViewDelegates are called according to events. when you set a collectionView delegate and it's **dataSource** to a VC swift will check these methods:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

and if you return zero in these methods no event for triggering delegates will be fired at all. so delegate methods will call after checking **dataSource**